# .NET Core Web Api enum binding

Tags: c#, enums, model-binding

I often encounter this situation when developing web apps where the client can choose/set an enum value (maybe through an API, not providing a select box like in frontend).
So I need to handle incorrect values. I am using **FluentValidation** with **Swagger** for this. I want to display enums as strings (Swagger) so I register the converter:

```
  services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

I have weird findings for enum modelbinding in .NET CORE:

Consider enum { A,B,C } and tested value bindings:

1. value "a" -> Enum.A  -> as expected
2. value 1 -> Enum.B -> as expected
3. value 10 -> 10 -> o_0 - is that new behaviour in CORE?
4. value "x" -> binding error -> as expected
5. value null -> Enum.A -> as expected

But how would I deal best with an invalid values?
I certainly do not want value 10 or Enum.A for null values.
I could think of two approaches:

i) Handle all invalid values like binding errors
ii) Bind invalid values to a an explicit invalid enum default Enum.Undefined and validate that this value never occurs

i) How would I enforce stricter binding?
ii) How can I force binding invalid values to Enum.Undefined?

**UPDATE**
I realized that `3)` is unchanged behaviour, I just did not came across this issue. I find that very counter intuitive though.
I also realized that I could write my own enum model binder but I do not want to overengineer things.

What I did for now is following:

enum MyEnum { undefined, a,b ,c}
and in `FluentValidation` validator:

```
 this.RuleFor(x => x.MyEnum ).Must(
                x =>
                    {
                        if (!Enum.IsDefined(x)) // can be crap!
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        // still can be Undefined
                        return x != MyEnum.Undefined;
                    });
```

This way I handle incorrect int values. Incorrect string values can not be handled that way because they will break at .NET model binding level. I guess I can live with that.

**UPDATE 2**
After some more thoughts about that issue I came up with following solution:
I just use string over enum in my DTO and therefore I can completely workaround model binding issues and use validations as follows:
this.RuleFor(x => x.Type).Must(
x => Enum.TryParse(typeof(MyEnum), x, out _));

Comment: `10` is indeed a valid value for any enum, regardless of how it's defined; this is a core aspect of how .NET handles enums. That is, `(MyEnum) 10` is always legal because an enum is nothing more than an integral type with a bunch of named constants attached.

Comment: Do note that your suggested workaround will still happily accept strings like `"10"`, which is still considered a valid value. If you don't want that, you'll need something like `Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(x, out var result) && Enum.IsDefined(result)`. Also note that while I'm flaunting the rules by posting (semi-)answers in comments, it's much  worse to do so in *questions*; you are allowed to self-answer your question.

Comment: Yes indeed I need to also check Enum.IsDefined. Btw, I also thought about writing an answer to myself but I am still not really satisfied with this solution.